# can't open pdf with wpf webbrowser

Tags: wpf, pdf, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to create an app to open a local PDF file using web browser in WPF. However the file doesn't open properly, instead displays a **grey blank screen**. The code works perfectly fine when used to open a HTML file. Please help!

[image]

Code:  `webBrowser1.Navigate(@"file:///C:/Working/sample.pdf");`

Note: I have adobe reader installed in my PC, if that is necessary. Is it?

Comment: I have the setup as you and the above code works perfectly fine. If you still have this problem post the XAML and the CS code and it will be easier to determine the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WPF by default uses IE-based WebBrowser. In order to be able to view PDF-files, you must have a plugin installed into IE which can display PDF-files.

In addition to grey background, this is what can happen with a PC where IE doesn't have a PDF-plugin (Acrobat Reader etc) installed:

[image: IE WPF PDF without plugin]

If you don't want to install plugins, one option to get around this issue is to use [Windows 10 APIs](https://blogs.u2u.be/lander/post/2018/01/23/Creating-a-PDF-Viewer-in-WPF-using-Windows-10-APIs) to draw the PDF.

Other option is a 3rd party library, like [CefSharp](https://cefsharp.github.io/). Here's steps for using CefSharp:

First install Nuget [CefSharp.WPF](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CefSharp.Wpf)

Second, change XAML from the default WebBrowser to:

```
    <wpf:ChromiumWebBrowser Loaded="ChromiumWebBrowser_Loaded" x:Name="Browser"></wpf:ChromiumWebBrowser>
```

Then create custom resolvers for CefSharp:

```
public class CustomProtocolSchemeHandler : ResourceHandler
{
    public CustomProtocolSchemeHandler()
    {
    }

    public override bool ProcessRequestAsync(IRequest request, ICallback callback)
    {
        return true;
    }
}

public class CustomProtocolSchemeHandlerFactory : ISchemeHandlerFactory
{
    public const string SchemeName = "customFileProtocol";

    public IResourceHandler Create(IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, string schemeName, IRequest request)
    {
        return new CustomProtocolSchemeHandler();
    }
}
```

Almost lastly, register the resolvers in App.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnLoadCompleted(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        var settings = new CefSettings();
        settings.RegisterScheme(new CefCustomScheme
        {
            SchemeName = CustomProtocolSchemeHandlerFactory.SchemeName,
            SchemeHandlerFactory = new CustomProtocolSchemeHandlerFactory(),
            IsCSPBypassing = true
        });

        settings.LogSeverity = LogSeverity.Error;
        Cef.Initialize(settings);
    }
}
```

Now everything should work:

[image: WPF PDF CefSharp]

More information about using CefSharp: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/881315/Display-HTML-in-WPF-and-CefSharp-Tutorial-Part

Answer (score 1):

I'll probably add a few changes to @Mikael's code (In case something didn't work out for you)

```
public class CustomProtocolSchemeHandler : ResourceHandler
{
    public CustomProtocolSchemeHandler()
    {
    }

    public override CefSharp.CefReturnValue ProcessRequestAsync(IRequest request, ICallback callback)
    {
        return CefSharp.CefReturnValue.Continue;
        
    }
}

public class CustomProtocolSchemeHandlerFactory : ISchemeHandlerFactory
{
    public const string SchemeName = "customFileProtocol";

    public IResourceHandler Create(IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, string schemeName, IRequest request)
    {
        return new CustomProtocolSchemeHandler();
    }
}
```